# Nível de detalhamento de casos de uso

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, projeto-de-software, uml, casos-de-uso

Estou começando a usar casos de uso pra documentar requisitos de sistemas orientados a objetos e estou com um pouco de dúvida quanto ao nível de detalhamento de um caso de uso. Basicamente, eu tenho dúvidas em relação a "*o que deve constar no cenário*". Vou dar dois exemplos disso: o primeiro deles é CRUD.

É comum encontrar requisitos de um sistema como "cadastrar/ler/editar/excluir produtos", ou analogamente pra clientes. De qualquer forma, o requisito é basicamente "fazer CRUD de tal entidade". Eu realmente fico em dúvida no quanto detalher de um caso de uso desses. Eu tenho duas possibilidades: simplesmente escrever um caso de uso "Manter Produtos" com cenário contendo um único passo "Manter dados dos produtos", por exemplo.

Ou posso fazer um caso de uso pra cada uma das operações, contendo todos os detalhes, como quais campos tem e tudo mais. No caso de CRUD qual dessas é a abordagem mais usada normalmente?

Existem ainda outros pontos dos sistemas que eu nem sempre sei muito bem o que realmente precisa ser detalhado num caso de uso. Pra explicar melhor isso vou pegar um exemplo de um sistema que estou desenvolvendo agora (para controle de um restaurante). Basicamente, o dono do restaurante ao inicio de cada expediente precisa ir no programa e criar uma nova sessão, ou seja, "inicializar as atividades do restaurante" dentro do sistema.

Esse caso de uso não é algo de CRUD, é realmente uma operação que um ator (o gerente) está interessado em fazer no sistema. Mas só consegui pensar em *um* passo: "Gerente inicializa nova sessão" e isso parece ser *muito* mais simplório do que deveria.

Não sei se consegui explicar muito bem com o exemplo o tipo de situação que estou falando. São situações em que parece que o único passo realmente é o que o próprio titulo do caso de uso diz e nesses casos fica dificil saber o que realmente detalhar

O quanto eu preciso detalhar em casos como esse? Apesar de ter dado esse exemplo, a pergunta é no geral mesmo, o exemplo é só pra ter algo concreto pra facilitar a pergunta.

Uma vez li sobre isso e falava-se bastante sobre entender quem vai ler isso, se é a equipe de perguntas e respostas, ou outra equipe, etc. Como eu trabalho sozinho, gostaria de saber como se lida com isso em casos como o meu, no qual não tem esse nível de formalidade e os casos de uso são escritos mais pra documentar e organizar os requisitos.

Comment: Considere adicionar a tag **[TAG:UML]** à sua pergunta. Seria a primeira pergunta do SOPT a fazer um uso adequado de tal tag, que até hoje foi muito mal tratada.

Comment: Não é uma questão adequadamente classificada como **projeto-de-software** (*software design*). Remover esta marca facilitará a localização de questões.

Answer (score 16):

## Não faça casos de uso de CRUD

Imagine o seguinte cenário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O Cliente pode realizar o caso de uso Remover Pedido sendo que ele nunca criou um pedido? Não, não pode. Tampouco pode consultar, alterar ou atualizar um pedido.

Os Casos de Uso devem representar as necessidades principais do sistema. Na figura acima foi criado um cenário pensando em funcionalidades, e isso deve ser evitado pois o objetivo dos casos de uso é dar contexto ao projeto, ele deve descrever os requisitos funcionais, ou seja, ele deve descrever o sistema sob a perspectiva do usuário. Em outras palavras, o diagrama de Casos de Uso deve fornecer uma visão gráfica resumida da operação do sistema.

A intenção principal do usuário no diagrama acima é **Criar Pedido**. Todos os elementos restantes se tornarão fluxos alternativos na especificação do caso de uso principal.

Outro problema gerado no diagrama acima é que a decomposição funcional, que é o ato de desmembrar um caso de uso em objetivos menores, gerando uma quantidade maior de casos de uso que possuem objetivos cada vez mais específicos. Essa estratégia vai contra a real finalidade do sistema, que deve descrever a parte funcional do sistema em objetivos macros, e ao desmembrá-los, temos várias ações isoladas que não representam as funcionalidades reais do sistema.

## Nomeando os casos de uso

Esqueça o nome "Manter produtos", você está cadastrando produtos, você não mantém os produtos, ninguém acessa o sistema para manter um produto. O termo "mantém" nesse contexto é completamente vago e não passa a real intenção do usuário.

"Inicializar nova sessão", esse sim é um suposto caso de uso completamente equivocado,  ele na verdade é apenas uma etapa de um fluxo de algum caso de uso. Ou seja, de maneira alguma ele é um caso de uso. Casos de uso são requisitos funcionais do seu sistema.

Pense no caso de uso como algo atômico, que você executa do início ao fim com um propósito bem definido, como algo que visa solucionar um problema que foi o motivo pelo qual o cliente decidiu comprar o seu sistema. Como uma dica, se quiser identificar se o caso de uso possui um fluxo completo ou não sempre imagine o cliente falando:

> Preciso de um sistema para poder [SUPOSTO CASO DE USO]

Para o exemplo acima, ficaria:

> Preciso de um sistema para poder "Inicializar uma nova sessão"

Ninguém compra um sistema para poder "Inicializar uma nova sessão". Seu sistema existiria se seu único caso de uso fosse "Inicializar uma nova sessão"? Não. Portanto ele não deve fazer parte do seu diagrama. Seu sistema põe um pedido, fecha uma conta, cadastra um cliente, faz recebimento de matérias primas, etc.. as coisas mais banais são apenas detalhes que serão especificadas em algum determinado documento do seu projeto.

Se o fluxo "Inicializar nova sessão" for utilizado inúmeras vezes por outros casos de uso você pode criar um **Caso de Uso de Inclusão** para ele, que representa um caso de uso sem um fluxo completo e consequentemente nunca interagirá com um Ator, ele apenas pode ser incluído por outros casos de uso em prol do reuso, evitando assim a repetição desnecessária de textos e possibilitando uma fácil manutenção dos casos de uso que incluem ele.

## Nomeando os atores

Não confunda papel com cargos ou até mesmo pessoas.

Você disse que criou um Ator gerente para cadastrar os produtos, será que só o gerente pode cadastrar? Nunca outro funcionário poderá fazer o papel de cadastrar produtos? Considere em dar um nome para seu Ator que represente que papel ele está assumindo na hora de executar o Caso de Uso. Que tal Mantenedor?

## Utilidade dos casos de uso

São 14 os tipos de diagramas que pertencem a linguagem UML, 7 estruturais e 7 comportamentais, ou seja, são mais diagramas do que costumamos sequer saber da existência, cada diagrama tem um propósito específico e bem definido, e a aplicabilidade de cada um varia de projeto para projeto, de ocasião para ocasião. O Diagrama de Caso de Uso não é exceção.

Como você disse que trabalha sozinho eu diria que uma situação em que o Diagrama de Casos de Uso pode ser importante é quando se utiliza a metodologia de desenvolvimento ICONIX. "Pode" ser importante pois obviamente tudo depende do tamanho e importância do seu projeto.

## Detalhando seu Caso de Uso

Cada Diagrama de Caso de Uso deve ser acompanhado de um documento que se chama de especificação, esse documento que possuirá uma análise muito mais detalhada. Um exemplo de tópicos que uma especificação aborda:

> 1. Nome do Caso de Uso
>      1.1 Breve Descrição
> 2. Fluxo de Eventos
>      2.1 Fluxo Básico
>      2.2 Fluxos Alternativos
> 3. Requisitos Especiais
> 4. Precondições
> 5. Pós-condições
> 6. Pontos de Extensão
> 7. Cenários
>      7.1 Cenários de Sucesso
>      7.2 Cenários de Insucesso

Comment: Só a frase de abertura da resposta já valia +1.

Comment: Ótima explicação, está clara e objetiva.

Answer (score 1):

Quanto à nomenclatura "Manter..." para casos de uso, você utiliza quando vai representar um conjunto de operações (CRUD). Pois, criar um caso de uso para cada operação poderia deixar o seu diagrama poluído (de difícil leitura). É um padrão seguido na representação de casos de uso. Não há nenhum problema com o uso do nome "Manter". O funcionamento do caso de uso é explicado na sua documentação.