# UML - Especificação de Caso de Uso

Tags: uml, casos-de-uso

Tenho de especificar um caso de uso 'Cadastrar Empresa (CRUD)', ao qual é utilizado por 3 atores:

- Funcionário (Que somente pode alterar a temperatura cadastrada na empresa)
- Atendente (Que é especialização de funcionário, e que pode cadastrar empresas)
- Síndico (Que é especialização de atendente)

A dúvida é: Como especificar as ações distintas dos atores no mesmo caso de uso?
[image: Diagrama de Casos de Uso]

Comment: No caso, é mesmo ator - algo como "o cara que cadastra empresas". Não são atores distintos só porque você planeja que a operação possa ser executada por pessoas de papéis distintos na organização.

Comment: Sim, mas ao especificar um fluxo básico eu tenho que considerar um ator, mas e os outros que  realizam operações distintas, eu tenho que criar outro fluxo básico na mesma especificação daquele caso de uso? ou o quê?

Comment: Embora faça uns 15 anos que não desenho um caso de uso formal, não me lembro de ter visto um caso de uso com mais de um ator. 1 caso de uso, 1 uso, 1 ator. Quanto ao que você **tem** que criar é relativo. Eu particularmente acho que você não tem que criar um caso de uso hehehe Depende da função desse diagrama; pra que você vai usar isso? Quem vai se beneficiar disso e com qual objetivo? Se for só um exercício, acho que você vai ter que perguntar pra quem pediu.

Comment: Mas em certo ponto, é apenas 1 ator, mas em perspectivas distintas.. Minha professora tinha dito para usar um fluxo alternativo, mas não sei como ficaria. Irei utilizar isso para realizar o projeto vigente do diagrama e outros futuros.

Comment: Tem muitos casos de usos desnecessários aí: "Efetuar login" é um deles, o caso de uso deve ser de funcionalidades completas, o login é apenas uma etapa de algum outro caso de uso relevante para o sistema. Acredito que algumas das suas dúvidas podem ser respondidas nesse post aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/20886/3117

Comment: Alguns Atores estão se confundindo com os cargos também. Eu preciso dar uma olhada no meu material dessa matéria para refrescar melhor a memória e te ajudar mais, mas veja se o outro link te ajuda por enquanto e se te levanta novas dúvidas.

Comment: Se para efetuar cada uma dessas ações o ator tem que se logar, então seu caso de uso não está sobre especificação correta. Efetuar login deveria ser um include de todos os casos. Em relação aos atores o caso de uso estipula o papel de cada ator dentro de um cenário. Portanto pode ser usar vários atores dentro do cenário, contando que eles tenham algum caso relacionado.Como também poderia criar casos de uso separados, mas que no seu exemplo por ser um modelo de pequeno porte não vejo a menor necessidade.

Answer (score 2):

O melhor seria criar um caso de uso básico que é incluído pelos outros casos de uso e criar três casos de uso para cada um dos atores poder fazer a sua parte (seja se identificar diferente ou mostrar uma tela de cadastro diferente). Ficaria mais fácil de trabalhar com os casos depois.

Se quiser mesmo fazer tudo em um caso de uso, é possível com o fluxo alternativo, mas aí o ator é único. O ator seria algo como "Usuário" e dentro do caso de uso você preenche como se fosse o caminho feliz (qual o ator padrão?) e pedindo que o usuário se identifique como síndico, atendente ou funcionário. Depois, nos fluxos alternativos, você mostra as sequências no caso de respostas de usuário se identificando como pessoas diferente do padrão.