# Dúvida sobre os Casos de Uso CRUD

Tags: uml, casos-de-uso

Estou com a seguinte dúvida sobre os Casos de Uso CRUD:

Fala-se que não deve criar vários casos de uso representando
cada operação do CRUD, e deve-se criar somente um caso de uso para isso, como explicado no
[Nível de detalhamento de casos de uso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20885/n%C3%ADvel-de-detalhamento-de-casos-de-uso).
Porém, e se somente o ator gerente, por exemplo, pudesse ter acesso para criar e remover, como ficaria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geralmente se usa o termo **manter** para indicar  os CRUD's, à muitas maneiras de se fazer caso de uso, não existe a maneira certa. Para casos assim eu geralmente crio o caso de uso **administrar** por exemlo, pode se usar extends para casos de uso de remover ou adicionar usuário, mas lembre, o caso de uso não deve ser complexo.

[image: Crud]

Encontrei esse caso de uso dentro do próprio stackoverflow, espero ter ajudado.